# How to handle TypeScript promises with conditional branches?

Tags: javascript, firebase, if-statement, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am accessing a firebase database and I would like to do the following.  When a user logs in, I need to check the state of a variable in the database.  Depending on the state of this variable, I then want to do one of two things.  My code looks like this, but isn't correct.

```
firebase.database( ).ref( `sessions/${user.uid}` ).once( 'value' )
  .then( ( data : firebase.database.DataSnapshot ) => {
    if( !data.exists( ) ) {
      console.log( 'No active sessions. Creating a new one' );
      const sessionKey = firebase.database( ).ref( `sessions/${user.uid}` ).push( ).key;
      return firebase.database( ).ref( `sessions/${user.uid}/${sessionKey}` ).update( {
        myStruct: {
          myValue: 123,
        }
      } );
    } else {
      console.log( 'Found an existing session' );
      const obj = data.val( );
      const sessionKey = Object.keys( obj )[0];
      return firebase.database( ).ref( `sessions/${user.uid}/${sessionKey}` ).once( 'value' );
    }
  } )
  .then( ( data : any ) => {
    //what is data here?  Is it coming from the .update call, or from the .once call ??
    //if this is coming from the update call then I want to perform some stuff,
    //however if it is coming from the .once call, then I want to retrieve the myStruct.myValue and perform some other stuff.
  } )
  .catch( ( error : firebase.auth.Error ) => {
    console.log( error );
  } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming from whichever one is returned.  You probably need to move that logic up into the other function, or at least add the context you need to the object that gets passed the final `.then`:

```
firebase...once( 'value' )
.then((data : firebase.database.DataSnapshot ) => {
  if(!data.exists()) {
    return firebase...update(/* ... */).then(
        (data: any) => {
            return {
                type: 'update',
                data: data
            }
        }
    );
  } else {
    return firebase...once('value').then(
        (data: any) => {
            return {
                type: 'once',
                data: data
            }
        }
    );
  }
}).then(( data : any ) => {
    if (data.type === 'update') {

    } else if (data.type === 'once') {

    }
});
```

Comment: very nice!  Thank you!

Comment: what about catching errors?  Do i need to add .catch() following the .then() in the return statement, or will a .catch at the end of the chain be sufficient?

Comment: just one `.catch` at the end should be sufficient